# intersection observer works only for the first video

Tags: javascript, jquery, intersection-observer

I need to pause a video if it is not in view
the below code works only for the first video in list
how to make it working for all `.bvideo` ?

```
<video class='bvideo' src='a.mp4' poster='a.jpg' preload='none' controls></video>
<video class='bvideo' src='b.mp4' poster='b.jpg' preload='none' controls></video>
<video class='bvideo' src='c.mp4' poster='c.jpg' preload='none' controls></video>

let io = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(!entry.isIntersecting){entry.target.pause();}
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    io.observe(document.querySelector('.bvideo'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use querySelectorAll() method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let bvideos = document.querySelectorAll('.bvideo');
    bvideos.forEach(bvideo => io.observe(bvideo));
});
```

Comment: I tried and result is the error in console - `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Comment: @provance - I have updated answer please check

Comment: no, you didn't change anything

Comment: let bvideos = document.querySelectorAll('.bvideo');
bvideos.forEach(bvideo => io.observe(bvideo));

Comment: Use loop for all elements to work as well